# Module copy of ansible 2.5 doesn't work as expected ( issue in return value )

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a problem with ansible 2.5 and i don't have the same behaviour as with 2.2.
When I copy a folder that contains a folder inside, which contains a file. I get an OK instead of Changed
Here is my example:

```
- name:  copy files share
  copy:
     dest: "/opt/"
     mode: 0644
     owner: root
     group: root
     src: "./share"
```

The state i get after running ansible, is "OK" and not "CHANGED". Even if it does the job correctly.
Can someone please give me an explication ???

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the synchronize module?

You could do something like this:

```
- name: sync folder1 with folder2
  synchronize:
    src: "./share"
    dest: "/opt"
```

You can get more info here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html